# Bootstrap 4 dropdown animation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, animation, dropdown

how can I use some animation on dropdowns?
Take a look on [stripe.com](https://stripe.com) footer and click on location or language links. I've record a video of this effect:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WV0h2zlE7fQ or worse GIF version http://g.recordit.co/w1S4fSrUBA.gif

It would be nice if some of those libs can be used:

- [Dynamics.js](http://dynamicsjs.com/)
- [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

My external html/js/css coder told me, that is impossible due fact, that Bootstrap 4 use `transform` property for positioning of dropdown menu itself.

Prepered jsfiddle with default bootstrap setup. https://jsfiddle.net/7hq03Lov/4/

Additional question - can be some any other animation applied on modal too?

Comment: I made something almost like this a while ago, perhaps you can base on it: https://codepen.io/phiter/pen/BZdXbv

Comment: @Phiter But that is not on bootstrap or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it via css, Change as per your need.

```
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    -webkit-animation: swing-in-top-fwd 1s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275) alternate both;
            animation: swing-in-top-fwd 1s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275) alternate both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes swing-in-top-fwd {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-100deg);
            transform: rotateX(-100deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
            transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
            transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes swing-in-top-fwd {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-100deg);
            transform: rotateX(-100deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
            transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
            transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
            transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```